# sort subdocument in mogodb4.0 by java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to sort subdocument by Java. I am not able to find the desired output. My data set is :

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b91668a0f77e30c11574c88"
    },
    "driverId": "22",
    "busId": "55",
    "startTime": {
        "$date": 1536255626852
    },
    "location": [
        {
            "latitude": 18.5803721,
            "longitude": 73.7447051,
            "position": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1536255628848
            }
        },
        {
            "latitude": 18.5803721,
            "longitude": 73.7447051,
            "position": 1,
            "status": 2,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1536255656122
            }
        },
        {
            "latitude": 18.5803721,
            "longitude": 73.7447051,
            "position": 1,
            "status": 2,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1536255656167
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b8c2cc70f77e322617c1ba1"
    },
    "driverId": "22",
    "busId": "55",
    "startTime": {
        "$date": 1535913159533
    },
    "location": [
        {
            "latitude": 18.5804663,
            "longitude": 73.7447209,
            "position": 0,
            "status": 1,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1535913160226
            }
        },
        {
            "latitude": 18.5804663,
            "longitude": 73.7447209,
            "position": 1,
            "status": 2,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1535913186460
            }
        },
        {
            "latitude": 18.5804663,
            "longitude": 73.7447209,
            "position": 1,
            "status": 2,
            "time": {
                "$date": 1535913187603
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

and the code i wrote :

```
AggregateIterable<Document> findIterable = tripsCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$match", new Document("busId", busId)),
            new Document("$sort", new Document("startTime", -1)),
            new Document("$sort", new Document("location.position", -1))));
```

When I am sorting the document by _Id or startTime, output comes accordingly. But when I am trying to sort subdocument, result set does not changes.

I tried some other variation as well:

```
Bson bsonFilterBus = Filters.eq("busId", busId);
Bson sortByDate = descending("startTime");
Bson sortByPosition = descending("location.position");
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = tripsCollection.find(bsonFilterBus).sort(sortByDate).sort(sortByPosition);
```

But results were same. i.e not sorted based on location.position

I am working with MongoDb 4.0. Somewhere I read, Mongo DB does not provide any method to sort subdocuments. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `$unwind` the sub documents followed by `$sort` by location's position field and `$group` to get back location array.

Something like

```
AggregateIterable<Document> findIterable = tripsCollection.aggregate(
     Arrays.asList(
      new Document("$match", new Document("busId", busId)),
      new Document("$unwind", "$location"),
      new Document("$sort", new Document("location.position", -1)),
      new Document("$group", 
           new Document("_id", "$_id")
            .append("driverId", new Document("$first","$driverId"))
            .append("busId", new Document("$first","$busId"))
            .append("startTime", new Document("$first","$startTime"))
            .append("location", new Document("$push","$location"))
      ),
      new Document("$sort", new Document("startTime", -1))
   )
);
```